# Convert TSQL to HSQL

Tags: hibernate, ejb-3.0, hsqldb, seam

How do I convert the following TSQL statement to HSQL.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT d.*, 
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY Year desc) AS dr
          FROM table_1 d) dd
 WHERE dr = 1
```

Comment: And so far, you've tried... what?

Comment: i don't think you ca hanve partation queries in HQL.. why don't you try to convert this to a db view and then use HQL to select from it.

Comment: Why do you want to write **HQL**? Since **DENSE_RANK()** is an oracle specific function there is not much meaning writing it in **HQL**. You are better of using **SQL** in the **createSQLQuery()** method.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response, I got answer for this. Please refer the answer section for the solution.

Comment: Oops I can't provide answer now, got a message which say wait for 8 hours. 
Any way I will put the answer here : 

select t1 from table_1 t1 where t1.year = ( select max(year) from table_1 where t1.C1=C1)

Answer (score 1):

select t1 from table_1 t1 where t1.year = ( select max(year) from table_1 where t1.C1=C1)